# Можно ли создать cookie для одного поддомена с основного домена?

Tags: javascript, cookie

Здравствуйте. 
На сайт [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie#%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-document-cookie) написано что можно в параметре `domain` указать либо основной домен, либо его поддомен, но у меня не получается создать куку для `one.example.com` с сайт `example.com`.

Про точку перед доменам знаю. Интересует создание куки для одного поддомена, находясь на основном домене.

Пример: находясь на сайте `javascript.ru` создать `cookie` доступную только для `learn.javascript.ru`:

```
var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 1000);
document.cookie = "name=value; 
domain=learn.javascript.ru; 
path=/; 
expires=" + date.toUTCString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень даже создается вот только вы не учитываете что она тут же удаляется. Из той же статьи.

> Если дата в прошлом, то кука будет удалена.

Вы указываете дату, равную текущему времени. Вот так все должно работать. Кука будет жить час.

```
var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 1000);
document.cookie = "test=test; domain=learn.javascript.ru; path=/; expires=" + new Date(date.getTime()+3600).toUTCString();
```

Так же обратите внимание что Ваши эксперименты будут работать только если вы используете консоль разработчика на **том же домене**. Вы не можете выдать куку одному домену, с другого.

### UPD.

Я не много не правильно Вас понял. `learn.javascript.ru`и `javascript.ru` это **разные** доменные имена. Находясь на `javascript.ru` Вы можете лишь установить куку для всех поддоменов `.javascript.ru`, по тому что это все еще "область видимости" этого домена. Однако `a.javascript.ru` - это уже **самостоятельный домен** со своей областью видимости. Вы уже не можете выдать ему куку.

#### Однако,

Если мы возьмем реальный случай, представим что у Вас несколько поддоменов и Вам очень нужно установить куку на один конкретный домен, например `forum.somesitename.local`.

Находясь на `somesitename.local`Вы можете отправить ajax запрос например на `forum.somesitename.local/?getCookie=on`, сервер будет знать что вам необходимо получить куку на этот домен и вернет `header` с [`Set-Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_cookies)

И все же, вы не сможете получить куку `forum.somesitename.local` с `somesitename.local`, если [на сервере нет соответствующих заголовков](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain#%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А можно уточнить как именно браузер проверяет корректность параметра `domain`.

Comment: То-есть находясь на сайте `somesitename.local` в параметре `domain` будет валиден только `somesitename.local`. Если находиться на сайте `forum.somesitename.local` то валидными будут значения `forum.somesitename.local` и `somesitename.local`. Есть ли документация описывающая проверку домена?